# Serialize Deserialize RuleDefinition

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, workflow-activity

I've created a Windows workflow `RuleDefinition` programmatically using the CodeDom objects in the rules object model.

I've serialized into a string to save it in a SharePoint list, using the method below.

I've deserialized the string to get the object `RuleDefinitions` using the method below, but it returns null and the error message:

> Could not deserialize object. The type 'http//schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/workflow.RuleDefinitions' could not be resolved

***Serialize Method***

```
DesignerSerializationManager dsm = new DesignerSerializationManager(); 
using (dsm.CreateSession()){                     
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();                     
using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter(stringBuilder))) {    
  WorkflowMarkupSerializer markupSerializer = new WorkflowMarkupSerializer();                         
  markupSerializer.Serialize(dsm, writer, ruleDeinitions);                         
  string rulesAsString = stringBuilder.ToString();
 }  
}
```

***Deserialize Method***

```
DesignerSerializationManager dsm = new DesignerSerializationManager(); 
using (dsm.CreateSession()){                     
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();                     
  using (XmlTextReader writer = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(xml)) ) {                        
  reader.Read();                         
  WorkflowMarkupSerializer markupSerializer = new WorkflowMarkupSerializer();                         
  RuleDefinitions ruleDefinitions = markupSerializer.Deserialize(dsm, reader) as  RuleDefinitions;
  if (dsm.Errors.Count > 0){                             
    WorkflowMarkupSerializationException error = dsm.Errors[0] as  WorkflowMarkupSerializationException;                            
    }
 }  
}
```

Any ideas?